# Test inapp purchase with debug key

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, apk

I'm trying to test inapp purchase, but every time when I deploy with eclipse (signed with the debug key), it says: 
*"This version of the application is not configured for Market billing. Check the help center for more information."*
When I export a release version of the apk (signed with my private key), it's ok. My question is this: I have to export an apk, upload it to the device, to run a test? That's a LOT of time wasted, and I cannot run tests either.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting signed APKs through ADT in Eclipse is indeed rather cumbersome. A much more effective build mechanism is to build debug or release versions through an Ant build script (see ["Building and Running from the Command Line"](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html)). I have added some Ant targets to install those freshly built APKs immediately onto the attached device.

If you create a new project through `android create project` (see ["Managing Projects from the Command Line"](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)), you'll get a basic build.xml to get started with.

Comment: With ANT it's OK. I build apx. 5 times a day, and I found it fast enough.

Answer (score 13):

You can buy the test product 'android.test.purchased' using a debug version. For a 'real' product, you need to sign with the release key and upload a draft version to market. To save time you should use the test product until you get your app working, and use the real product ID for final testing only. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) for more details

Comment: This is useful too as it clears up the main difference between 'real' products and the static responses.

Comment: If you use the 'android.test.purchased' next time you query the inventory you will receive an error, as the 'android.test.purchased' is broken and it does not pass the validation process.

Comment: If you looked at the documentation, I would see that now they require you to upload the app to the alpha or beta channel in order to test IAP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had to install the app from the market itself before it worked.  Sideloading the same APK didn't work for some reason.